# Avoiding simultaneous acces to a shared resource in a web application

Tags: php, web, laravel-5

I have a web application consisting of users having projects , projects belong to to a single user and are access by the URI`:root/project/[pid`] .

Now I have a middleware to restrict users from accessing each others projects. Although  I also have a feature in my web application by which an user may share their projects with other users, so multiple users can access a single shared project.

The problem is I don't want them to access the same project simultaneously ,  say if project1 is shared by user1 and user2 . URI root/project/project1_id  could be accessed by both but not at the same time .

I am currently thinking how I could do this , I have some ideas but wanted to know if there is best or easier way to do this.

I am thinking of altering the project table in the database to have an active flag which would be set to true every time any user accesses the project web page and unset when he/she leaves the webpage or the session ends.

But I have not sure if this would be the best way to go .

I am using laravel as a framework for my web application . So a solution within that framework would be great

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to limit access to one person? Are you worried about two people editing the same page/whatever simultaneously?

Comment: Your approach seems decent to me.  But you'll have to have some way of _un_locking  access as well.  This could be handled by an expiry on the lock  (locked_until).  Knowing when a web user is "finished" is a tricky problem, so an expiry is necessary because you can't count on the user unlocking the file for you.  But if you want to push that responsibility to the user, you could do so.  The other option would be to use a check-and-set approach to saving, and then allow 2 people to attempt access simultaneously and error when changes were made in the interim.

Comment: @willis ,it because a project can be edited and if I allow the same elements of the project to edit more or less at the same time it might get ugly

Comment: @dan ,check and save approach?  also was thinking of catching page request and session expiry to check for user exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the below mentioned solution to the problem:

I added a updated_at timestamp and update_by column in my project table which get update evertime someone updates the project

In the front end I set up a long poll function which checks the project table every couple of seconds

If there is a update in project in the past 5 seconds or so by someone other than me I fetched the entire updated project in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

[Store a version number with each project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

When someone starts to edit something in the project, send the current version number to the browser. When saving the edits, send the version number back to the server. If the version numbers match, then save the changes and increment the version. If the version numbers don't match, then someone else has edited the project in the meantime. While a user is editing, periodically call the server to check if the version number has changed and display "another user has changed this project" if it has. You could also save something to the database every time someone starts editing something, so if a second person starts editing the project within a certain time interval, you can display "X is editing this project."

I would use this strategy rather than having a lock that prevents a second person from even starting a new edit, because on the web it's hard to determine if an action that was started will ever be completed. If a user starts an edit but then gets distracted and leaves the browser open, other edits to that project will be blocked until your lock times out.

Comment: This is good, but I would set a checkin/checkout or lock type flag.  When user1 starts editing, set that flag in the db with an expiry time.  When user2 goes to view it, instead of the edit button or whatever tell them "user1 is editing this file and it is locked until $DATE/TIME or user1 completes teh edit".   On user1s screen you should either be updating the lock until via ajax while he works, and release it on a save/exit/republish

Comment: That would work. The optimistic strategy gives you the opportunity to allow users to make non-conflicting changes in parallel. Maybe two users are editing a page, but they're changing different sections. You could allow the first user to save, then import those changes into the second user's editor while the second user is still making changes to the other section.